# Is a chosen ciphertext attack on PGP still possible?

Tags: pgp, chosen-ciphertext-attack, cfb

In a [paper from 2002](https://www.schneier.com/academic/paperfiles/paper-pgp.pdf) (pdf), Jallad et al describe a chosen ciphertext attack on PGP by taking advantage of the CFB mode that the block ciphers use under PGP. It's quite a devastating attack.

Is this attack still viable in 2016 or has PGP made changes?

Comment: PGP definitely _can_ defend against this sort of attack (which exploits the complete lack of authentication). The more important question is: What do the implementations do by default nowadays?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/GnuPG/comments/37mf9f/gpg_authenticated_encryption/ is probably an interesting read. I don't see any authentication ciphers in GnuPG at the moment and the comment linked to is only of 11 months ago...

Comment: IIRC it depends on the specifications, so it is still possible. I do not remember if OpenPGP format specifies a new version of ciphertext adding an integrity check before decryption, but, if one is able to downgrade the version of ciphertext it could be posisble to implement the same attack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[RFC 4880, OpenPGP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) (superseded RFC 2440 which was up to date in 2002) contains a [chapter on security considerations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-14), which also discusses the decryption oracle attack Jallad et al described:

> In late summer 2002, Jallad, Katz, and Schneier published an
> interesting attack on the OpenPGP protocol and some of its
> implementations [JKS02].  In this attack, the attacker modifies a
> message and sends it to a user who then returns the erroneously
> decrypted message to the attacker.  The attacker is thus using the
> user as a random oracle, and can often decrypt the message.
>
> Compressing data can ameliorate this attack.  The incorrectly
> decrypted data nearly always decompresses in ways that defeat the
> attack.  However, this is not a rigorous fix, and leaves open some
> small vulnerabilities.  For example, if an implementation does not
> compress a message before encryption (perhaps because it knows it
> was already compressed), then that message is vulnerable.  Because
> of this happenstance -- that modification attacks can be thwarted
> by decompression errors -- an implementation SHOULD treat a
> decompression error as a security problem, not merely a data
> problem.
>
> This attack can be defeated by the use of Modification Detection,
> provided that the implementation does not let the user naively
> return the data to the attacker.  An implementation MUST treat an
> MDC failure as a security problem, not merely a data problem.
>
> In either case, the implementation MAY allow the user access to the
> erroneous data, but MUST warn the user as to potential security
> problems should that data be returned to the sender.
>
> While this attack is somewhat obscure, requiring a special set of
> circumstances to create it, it is nonetheless quite serious as it
> permits someone to trick a user to decrypt a message.
> Consequently, it is important that:
>
> 1. Implementers treat MDC errors and decompression failures as
>    security problems.
> 2. Implementers implement Modification Detection with all due
>    speed and encourage its spread.
> 3. Users migrate to implementations that support Modification
>    Detection with all due speed.

As a consequence, the OpenPGP packets ["Sym. Encrypted Integrity Protected Data Packet (Tag 18)
"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.13) and ["Modification Detection Code Packet (Tag 19)
"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.14) have been introduced, together forming an modification detection system (which is the proposed mitigation by Jallad et al):

> NON-NORMATIVE EXPLANATION

> The MDC system, as packets 18 and 19 are called, were created to
> provide an integrity mechanism that is less strong than a
> signature, yet stronger than bare CFB encryption.

> It is a limitation of CFB encryption that damage to the ciphertext
> will corrupt the affected cipher blocks and the block following.
> Additionally, if data is removed from the end of a CFB-encrypted
> block, that removal is undetectable.  (Note also that CBC mode has
> a similar limitation, but data removed from the front of the block
> is undetectable.)

> [...]

At least GnuPG uses these packets per default, which you can verify through `gpg --list-packets` or `pgpdump`:

```
$ echo "foo" | gpg --recipient a4ff2279 --encrypt | pgpdump
Old: Public-Key Encrypted Session Key Packet(tag 1)(524 bytes)
    New version(3)
    Key ID - 0xCC73B287A4388025
    Pub alg - RSA Encrypt or Sign(pub 1)
    RSA m^e mod n(4093 bits) - ...
        -> m = sym alg(1 byte) + checksum(2 bytes) + PKCS-1 block type 02
New: Symmetrically Encrypted and MDC Packet(tag 18)(63 bytes)
    Ver 1
    Encrypted data [sym alg is specified in pub-key encrypted session key]
        (plain text + MDC SHA1(20 bytes))
```

In GnuPG, you can enforce usage of the new packets through the `--force-mdc` option (which can also be applied permanently in `gpg.conf`). From `man gpg`:

> Force  the use of encryption with a modification detection code. This is always used with the newer ciphers (those with a blocksize greater than 64 bits), or if all of the
> recipient keys indicate MDC support in their feature flags.

Comment: This answer is thorough and explanatory, thank you for taking the time to write it